# Powershell to pull properties based on multiple criteria

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a list of AD users who have no manager listed and a value of Employee in a custom field `usertype`.

When I run this, it does not filter but gives me all accounts - users, resources, etc.  I can add `usertype` or manager to the select fields and see that it isn't pulling correctly (manager is populated or `usertype` is not Employee).

What do I need to change to get the correct data?

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * |  Select Name, SamAccountName, Department 
where-object userType -eq 'Employee' -and Manager -eq $null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the custom `userType` attribute is [indexed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/indexed-attributes), then in both cases you can leverage the [Active Directory Filter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)):

```bash
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(!manager=*)(userType=Employee))" -Properties Department |
    Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, Department
```

To give a brief explanation on what the [LDAP Filter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) is doing:

```bash
(&                       # AND, all conditions must be met
    (!manager=*)         # manager attribute is not populated
    (userType=Employee)  # usertype attribute is equal to "Employee"
)                        # close then AND clause
```

If the custom attribute is not indexed, then the filtering must be done with PowerShell:

```bash
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!manager=*)" -Properties Department, userType |
    Where-Object userType -EQ 'Employee' |
    Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, Department
```

If you also need to find **Enabled** users only then you can include the following to your filter:

```bash
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(!manager=*)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" -Properties ...
```

As for why your code is failing, you have a missing pipe after your `Select-Object` statement and when filtering for multiple conditions with `Where-Object`, we must use a [scriptblock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.3#-filterscript). In conclusion, the following would've worked (but a lot slower than the above examples).

```bash
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Department, userType, Manager |
    Where-Object { $_.userType -eq 'Employee' -and -not $_.Manager } |
    Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, Department
```

Comment: The not indexed script worked great, but I also noticed I have disabled users in the results.  I tried adding (!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2) in the where-object, but get positional parameter error.  The enabled filter would go in the where-object section correct?  How do I specify this other condition in addition to the usertype condition?

Comment: @mrcgray that needs to go in the LDAP Filter. See the update

Answer (score 0):

Where possible, filter first. It is much faster and easier to process that way, in general.

```
Get-AdUser -Filter 'userType -eq "Employee" -and Manager -notlike "*"' |
Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, Department
```

If Manager doesn't support filtering with notlike, then this:

```
Get-AdUser -Filter 'userType -eq "Employee"' -Properties Manager |
Where-Object{-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Manager)} |
Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, Department
```